# ls doesn't produce the same output from Linux to MacOs

Tags: c, linux, macos, command, ls

I am rewriting my own implementation of ls and I have found out that it doesn't work the same on my Macbook and my Xubuntu virtual machine.

The behavior I am testing is the use of a flag after the name of a directory, for example (Desktop and ft_ls are both directories):

```
/bin/ls -a Desktop -r ft_ls
```

produces this output on my Mac

```
ls: -r: No such file or directory
Desktop:
.       ..      .DS_Store   .localized

ft_ls:
.       ..      .git        Makefile    ft_ls       ft_ls.a     includes    libft       main.c      srcs        test
```

As you can see -r is considered as a file or a directory, however on my virtual machine with approximatively the same command -r is considered as an option (Bureau and ft_ls are both directories):

```
/bin/ls -a Bureau -r ft_ls
```

produces this output on Xubuntu

```
ft_ls:
srcs  Makefile    main.c    libft  .git  .dist  ..    .

Bureau/:
terminator.desktop  libft  ..  .
```

You can reproduce this behavior on your own system with:

```
/bin/ls -a "Any directory" -r "Any directory"
```

Am I doing something wrong or ls is different between Linux and Macos ? Thank you for your answers !

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Your images are unreadable — [don't put images into questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Put all options before the first non-option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU C library version of [`getopt()`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) thinks that you should be allowed to interleave options and arguments and therefore interprets the `-r` as an option, permuting the argument array to move the `-r` before the actual file arguments.

The POSIX specification for [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) does not specify this behaviour, and many non-GNU implementations of `getopt()` do not permute the argument list.  Macs (and presumably BSD systems) do not automatically use GNU `getopt()` — AFAIK, you'd have to install it and link with that library before linking with the system library.

On GNU systems, you can set the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` to suppress the permutation of options — I normally run with this set on my work machines and have to have cover scripts for a couple of work-provided scripts that rely on `POSIXLY_CORRECT` not being set — the cover scripts unset the variable and then run the official script.

Note that using `--` as an option means that anything following it is not an option; the arguments after the `--` option will be treated as non-option arguments by `getopt()`.

For portable work, ensure that you put options before other arguments.  And if you're running multiple commands that run other commands, use `--` liberally.

One command sequence I use routinely is a variation on:

```
repeat -n 25 -i 300 -d 120 -c -- timecmd -m -- cvl
```

The `repeat` command repeats the command after the first double-dash (`--`) 25 times, with an initial delay of 300 seconds, thereafter a delay of 120 seconds, and prints out the repeat count in the identifying information.  The `timecmd -m` times how long the command after the second `--` takes, reporting in milliseconds.  The `cvl` command looks at the current build log, reporting on the progress of the build and analyzing the log file for errors.  It's crucial that the `-m` option is not interpreted by `repeat` (because it isn't a valid option to `repeat`).  The `--` ensures that the `-m` is given to `timecmd` and not subsumed by `repeat`.  Timing the `cvl` command tells me if there are delays caused by network or other problems.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it, basically getopt() implementations on Linux allows passing options to your command anywhere on the line but the one on my Mac considers that after passing my options the rest of the arguments are treated as non-option arguments?

Comment: @luweglarz — yes, that interpretation is correct.  The GNU behaviour deviates from historical precedent.  Sometimes, innovations are welcome.  Personally, I don't welcome this one.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer it makes more sense now !

Comment: @luweglarz It's not that consistent, and sometimes varies between different commands on the same platform. For example, on both platforms, `find` requires that options be passed before the path(s) to search, because after that they'd be confused with search criteria. Similarly, `ssh` is the same program on both platforms (openssh), and has the same syntax, which allows command options both before and after the first non-option parameter (the remote host to connect to), but not after the *second* non-option parameter (the remote command); anything after that is an option to the remote command.